# How can I demonstrate that this type will be inferred?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, type-inference

I am going over, Haskel type inference which is a bit tricky for me even though it seems easy.

Given this function: `nat x = x : ( nat (x+1))`

which is of type: `Num t => t -> [t]`

and this is clear because nat function takes an element and constructs an infinite list.

But, now I am asked to specify the type of `head (nat 2)`

I fully understand why and what is the type of `head :: [a] -> a`

But why is `head (nat 2) :: Num c => c` can someone explain why?

Starting from the most general type which is A -> B (I assume its A -> B because it takes one argument) Whats next?

***EDIT***

This `Give the type of the expression: head (nat 2)` means that I should give the type of the function, or simply just the value returned, which in fact must be a number and that's why it is `Num c => c`, did I just answered my question?

Original question:  `Give the type of the expression: head (nat 2)`

Justify your answer.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? You specified the type of `nat` and the type of `head`, why is the result confusing when you combine them?

Comment: what do you mean combine them

Comment: Your question is "Give the type..." and you state it is `Num c => c`. What is your question? You combined the types of `2`, `nat`, and `head` through function application.

Answer (score 10):

Well let us assume that we already derived the type of `nat` and we know the type of [**`head :: [a] -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:head)

```
nat :: Num a => a -> [a]
head :: [b] -> b
```

Then we use different type variable names `a` and `b`, since right now we do not know anything about `a` and `b`, and hence we assume that the *can* be different, and hence assign a different name.

Now we see `(nat 2)` in the expression. We know that `2` has type:

```
2 :: Num c => c
```

So that means that `nat 2` has type:

```
nat     :: Num a => a -> [a]
2       :: Num c => c
----------------------------
(nat 2) :: Num a =>      [a]
```

and we know that `a ~ c` (`a` and `c` are the same type). We know this since `2` is the *parameter* of a function call with `nat` as function, and `nat` has as parameter type `a`. Hence the type of `2` and the parameter of `nat` need to be the same.

Now we call `head` with as argument `(nat 2)`, so that means we reason that:

```
head         ::          [b] -> b
(nat 2)      :: Num a => [a]
---------------------------------
head (nat 2) :: Num b =>        b
```

And we know that `a ~ b` since the type of `nat 2` is `[a]` and the first parameter of `head` should have type `[b]`. So that means that since `a ~ b`, that means that the type constraint `Num a`, also means `Num b`, and vice versa.

So the type is:

```
head (nat 2) :: Num b => b
```

Comment: This is the best answer I could ever think of, Thank You!.

Comment: I understand how the types are being passed around now. clearly informative comment.

Comment: you know that moment, when u read it 10 times, and you get it, you finally get it!

Comment: sorry for taking too long, but do you know any good resources on type inference in haskell?

Comment: @NarrowVision: well the algorithm behind Haskells type system is the *Hindley–Milner type system* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) I think this might be a start. There is some explanation about *algorithm W* which is the algorithm that does the type inference.

Comment: Mark Jones's thesis is (though it's from 1994), definitive in Haskell type inference: https://www.amazon.com/Qualified-Types-Practice-Distinguished-Dissertations/dp/0521543266 An earlier tech-report version is available for free (though it's scanned) at https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/3432/PRG106.pdf

Comment: Thank you guys, I will definitely look into that.